# Laravel 8 connection at the web app with api

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-8

For my job, I have to make an app which never use the database directly. I have to only request an API even for the connection.

So... There is my problem. I try to make an auth with a user that i'm getting from API but i'm always redirect to the login page.

My API auth :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = request(['use_username', 'password']);
    $this->guard()->factory()->setTTL(config('jwt.ttl') * 12);
    if (!$token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    $user = auth()->user();
    return $this->respondWithToken($user, $token);
}

protected function respondWithToken($user, $token)
{
    $cookie = cookie('jwt', $token, 60 * 12); // 12h
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ])->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

My web app auth :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $response = Http::post(env('app_url').'/api/auth/login', $request->only('use_username', 'password'));
    $cookie = cookie('jwt', $response['token'], 60 * 12); // 12h
    $user = ( new User() )->forceFill( $response['user'] );
    if (Auth::login($user)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    flash('error')->error();
    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ]);
}
```

My API guard (default guard) :

```
'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false
    ]
```

The goal is to authenticate the user in the API, get a JWT token and auth the user in the web app with the same user that got in the API. After, all my request to the API have to use the JWT token get during the login... Maybe with a HttpOnly cookie ?

Well, i can't connect my user to the web app, i'm always unauthenticate and redirect to th elogin form, can someone help me ?

I'm using [tymon/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) library with PHP 8

Comment: Did you check your .env file? Is there any jwt_token?

Comment: @MDMasudSikdar yes i got the JWT_SECRET env variable